# Why is the Ricci tensor diagonal for isotropic spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, curvature

I'm reading Zee's [*Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691145587/einstein-gravity-in-a-nutshell) and while calculating the Ricci tensor for FRW spacetime he claims that because the spacelike slices of constant $t$ are rotationally invariant, the off-diagonal elements of the Ricci tensor vanish (working in $t$, $r$, $\theta$, $\phi$ coordinates). Without calculating the Ricci tensor from the Christoffel symbols element-by-element, can someone provide an explanation of why this is true? More generally is there a good way to see how symmetries of the metric, like rotation or time translation, etc. translate to properties of the Ricci or Einstein tensor?